# Set property value from another property where List() is used

Tags: c#, properties

How can I set a property from another property where a `List<string>()` is used?

As shown below, in `EnableTest1` I want to set the bool property `EnableTest2` 
as false so it always returns a false for when `EnableTest1` is true.

```
public class Test
{

   public List<string> _list;
   public Test(List<string> list)
   {
       _list = list;
   }

   public bool EnableTest1 => _list.All(x => x == "Test1");
   public bool EnableTest2 => _list.All(x => x == "Test2");
   public bool EnableTest3 => _list.All(x => x == "Test3"); 
   public bool EnableTest4 => _list.All(x => x == "Test4");
}
```

Comment: So you want to have a setter for each property that essentially overrides the behaviour you have in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check `EnableTest1` for being `false`:

```
public bool EnableTest2 => !EnableTest1 && _list.All(x => x == "Test2");
```

Now, if `EnableTest1` is `true` then `EnableTest2` is always `false` and if `EnableTest2` we check `_list` items.

**Code:**

```
public class Test {

  public List<string> _list;

  public Test(List<string> list) {
    // We should validate public members arguments
    if (null == list)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));

    _list = list;
  }

  public bool EnableTest1 => _list.All(x => x == "Test1");
  public bool EnableTest2 => !EnableTest1 && _list.All(x => x == "Test2");
  public bool EnableTest3 => _list.All(x => x == "Test3");
  public bool EnableTest4 => _list.All(x => x == "Test4");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry this solution helped me achieve the desired result :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but how's this?

```
public class Test
{

   public List<string> _list;
   public Test(List<string> list)
   {
       _list = list;
   }

   public bool EnableTest1 => _list.All(x => x == "Test1");
   public bool EnableTest2 => EnableTest1 && _list.All(x => x == "Test2");
   public bool EnableTest3 => EnableTest2 && _list.All(x => x == "Test3"); 
   public bool EnableTest4 => EnableTest3 && _list.All(x => x == "Test4");
}
```